# How wordfence runs scan in background?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordfence

Normally I see that whenever we send request to PHP it processes the request and sends the response and process ends here. But Wordfence (Wordpress Plugin) performs scan continuously even if we refresh the webpage.

I also want to build similar functionality to perform long running batch operations.

Can anybody explain how Wordfence continuously runs its process even after page refresh?

Comment: The scan generally runs in the background, and the admin interface is just polling the scan’s progress periodically. The background process is launched by Wordfence making a standard HTTP GET to the local Wordfence, and listening for that using a `wp_ajax_` hook. The scan itself is composed of several jobs, and once a job is complete, Wordfence moves on to the next. There’s also some serialization logic for if the process needs to sleep and be woken up later.

Comment: then how it keeps running even after changing the page?

Comment: Wordfence makes a call to (effectively) itself using `wp_remote_get`, without a timeout set to `0.01`, which is pretty much immediate. The function that gets invoked uses [`ignore_user_abort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) which allows PHP to continue processing, even if a client disconnect is detected.

Comment: "without a timeout" should have been "with a timeout"

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas I didn't knew about this function ignore_user_abort. I will check  and try to build something. If I face any issues I will reply here.

Comment: Why not inspect the source code of that plugin to see how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ChrisHaas

ignore_user_abort() function really worked for me. I was looking something like this. Thank you very much. Thank You! Thank You!